# Quarkus guide "Packaging And Releasing With JReleaser" not working

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

When working through [guide "Packaging And Releasing With JReleaser"](https://quarkus.io/guides/jreleaser) and "5. Creating the distribution" with "./mvnw -Pdist package" this error occurs

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.5.0:single (make-distribution) on project simple-quarkus-app: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: /Users/xxx/simple-quarkus-app/target/simple-quarkus-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -> [Help 1]

I tried to install graalvm and also to use mandrel.
Want to release a quarkus app for linux/macos/windows on github-releases

My OS is macos/aarch64

Thank you
Tom

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

- install graalvm
- compile to native binary with `./mvnw -Pnative package`
- create your distribution with `./mvnw -Pdist package` (or just use `./mvnw -Pdist -Pnative clean package`)
- now you will find your files ./target/distributions